# Array.length gives incorrect length

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array having object as values at the indices like:

```
var a = [];
a[21] = {};
a[90] = {};
a[13] = {};
alert(a.length); // outputs 91
```

I have found a workaround to get the actual length:

```
function getLength(arr) {
    return Object.keys(arr).length;
}
var a = [];
a[21] = {};
a[90] = {};
a[13] = {};
alert(getLength(a));
```

**But, why does JS gives incorrect length when objects are stored at random indices?** It just adds 1 to the largest index found on an array. Like in the above example, 90 was the largest index. It just adds 1 and gives 91 as output. [Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tc4f0rz1/)

Comment: The behavior you're describing is what's defined in the official spec. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2

Comment: The question is: Why do you have incorrect assumptions about `.length`? Just imagine `.length` returned `3` and you tried to use `for` loop to get the values. You'd never get the values...

Comment: @CoryDanielson Thanks. Didn't know that official spec like this existed! I will always refer to it now.

Comment: @FelixKling Couldn't understand what you said. I ain't good at English :P I need such indices because they have facilitated alot in my script. I thought finding a fix for `.length` would be good. All else works fine.

Comment: Well, it sounded like you expected `.length` to return a different value, presumably `3`. But if it returned `3` and you iterated over the array with `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` and would access `arr[i]`, which would be `arr[0]`, etc, then you would not get the correct values.

Comment: Either way, it seems like what you want is actually an object (`var a = {}`), not an array.

Comment: @CoryDanielson—BTW, the official version is now [*ed 6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html). ;-)

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding Array.length documentation in there..... :o

Comment: @CoryDanielson—it's under [*§22.1.4 Properties of Array Instances*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-array-instances).

Comment: ahh way down there... lil javascript spec is growing up :')

Comment: With ed 5 ECMA seem to have kept as much as possible of the numbering from ed 3, however that meant some sections were just references to other sections, and stuff wasn't necessarily in a logical sequence. With ed 6 they seem to have bitten the bullet, put everything back in order and renumbered.

Comment: I have to admit I was surprised when I faced this issue , but then it makes sense , Javascript Arrays are just objects :)

Comment: @KennyXu - what a useless comment. Needlessly aggressive. You're in no position to point people towards learning things when you're asking about vertically aligning divs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because [**`length`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) gives you the next `index` available in the array.

[**DOCS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

**arrayLength**

> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 2^32-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with length set to that number.

[**ECMA Specifications**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2)

Because you don't have inserted any element in the other keys than 21, 90, 13, all the remaining indexes contains `undefined`. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4aupfgp4/1/)

To get actual number of elements in the array:

```js
var a = [];
a[21] = {};
a[90] = {};
a[13] = {};

var len = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] !== undefined) {
    len++;
  }
}
document.write(len);
```

**Shorter version**

```js
var a = [];
a[21] = {};
a[90] = {};
a[13] = {};


for (var i = 0, len = 0; i < a.length; i++, a[i] !== undefined && len++);


document.write(len);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4aupfgp4/3/)

**EDIT**

If the array contains large number of elements, looping to get its length is not the best choice.

As you've mentioned in the question, **`Object.keys(arr).length`** is the best solution in this case, considering that you don't have any properties added on that array. Otherwise, the `length` will not be what you might be expecting.(Thanks To @RobG)

Comment: Thanks. I can understand it now. But, what if I have `a[2020] = {}`? I think looping through all the array ain't quite good. I will stick to my method for now until someone else comes up with a nicer solution. IDK how fast is `Object.keys` but it will be faster than loop atleast.

Comment: *Object.keys* will return all own properties, which might not all be indexes.

Comment: @RobG Can you please explain, how this will affect in this scenario of array

Comment: @Tushar— `var a = []; a.foo = 'foo';`. Now `a.length` is 0 but `Object.keys(a).length` is 1.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for the explanation. But, I don't think OP might do something this. Just a thought

Comment: @RobG I ain't gonna put properties there but thanks for giving such valuable info.

Comment: @Tushar–there is often a debate about whether or not it's a good idea to treat arrays as objects if you have a mix of data types. Just pointing out one possible side effect of doing that (which might be moot, or not). ;-)

Comment: As I've just discovered, this is also relevant if [using the `delete` keyword to remove array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements). Consider using splice() or pop() instead.

Comment: Great answer, but what a weird JS method name, sounds like a bit of a misnomer

Answer (score 6):

The array in JavaScript is a simple zero-based structure. The `array.length` returns the `n + 1` where `n` is the maximum index in an array.

That's just how it works - when you assign 90'th element and this array's length is less than 90, it expands an array to 90 and sets the 90-th element's value. All missing values are interpreted as `null`.

If you try the following code:

```
var a = [];
a[21] = {};
a[90] = {};
a[13] = {};
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

You will get the following JSON:

> [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{}]

Moreover, `array.length` is not a readonly value.
If you set a `length` value *less* than the current, then the array will be resized:

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
 arr.length = 3;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
 // [1,2,3]
```

If you set a `length` value *more* than the current, then the array will be expanded as well:

```
 var arr = [1,2,3];
 arr.length = 5;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
 // [1,2,3,null,null]
```

In case you need to assign such values, you can use JS objects.
You can use them as associative array and assign any key-value pairs.

```
var a = {};
a[21] = 'a';
a[90] = 'b';
a[13] = 'c';
a['stringkey'] = 'd';
a.stringparam = 'e'; // btw, a['stringkey'] and a.stringkey is the same

console.log(JSON.stringify(a)); 
// returns {"13":"c","21":"a","90":"b","stringkey":"d","stringparam":"e"}

console.log(Object.keys(a).length);
// returns 5
```

Comment: I see. You suggested using JS Objects but how do I simulate the same behaviour as arrays? Just supply the index and get a value.

Comment: BTW "missing" values aren't "*interpreted as null*" (and script consoles to not report them that way). Accessing a missing member returns *undefined*, exactly the same as accessing a non–existent property of any object. A member will only have the value *null* if it has been assigned that value, in which case it isn't "missing". ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Because that's the behavior of Array.length as described in the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2).

> The length property of this Array object is a data property whose value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable property whose name is an array index.

So Array.length is always the last item's index + 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a[90] as largest index so the index is starting from 0 to 90 becomes 91 in length.

And where you didn't pass the values like a[80], etc. javascript will store them as hole i.e. for eg `[1, , 3, , ,90]` where commas are used indicates the hole in array.

If you try to access those values then you'll get `undefined`.