Max call stack exceeded for Math.random
I have an array of fruits. I want to fill an array of size 12 with fruits such that every fruit in the new array has even number of occurrences.


const fruitsList = [
  { id: 1, img: "/apple.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 2, img: "/banana.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 3, img: "/cherry.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 4, img: "/coconut.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 5, img: "/grapes.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 6, img: "/lemon.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 7, img: "/muskmelon.jpg", flipped: false },
  { id: 8, img: "/watermelon.jpg", flipped: false },
];

let randomOrderedFruits = [];

const generateRandomFruits = () => {
  const arrLength = Object.keys(randomOrderedFruits).length;
  if (arrLength === 12) return;
  const randomIndexOfFruit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  let timesToRepeat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  timesToRepeat = timesToRepeat % 2 === 0 ? timesToRepeat : timesToRepeat + 1;
  fillWithRandom(timesToRepeat, randomIndexOfFruit);

  generateRandomFruits();
};
const usedIndices = {};

const fillWithRandom = (timesToRepeat, randomIndexOfFruit) => {
  if (timesToRepeat === 0 || randomOrderedFruits.length === 12) return;
  //repeat selected randomIndexOfFruit such that it occurs 2 or 4 times.
  for (let i = 0; i < timesToRepeat; i++) {
    const randomIndexToInsertAt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    if (usedIndices[randomIndexToInsertAt]) {
      fillWithRandom(timesToRepeat, randomIndexOfFruit);
    } else {
      usedIndices[randomIndexToInsertAt] = true;
      randomOrderedFruits[randomIndexToInsertAt] = fruitsList[randomIndexOfFruit];
    }
  }
};

const randomizedFruits = generateRandomFruits();

console.log(randomizedFruits)



What I'm doing above is select a random index of fruitsList.
Again generate a random number to determine how many times the selected random index must be in new array(either 2 or 4 times).
Then selecting a random index of new array at which the fruit must be inserted.
My code gives max call stack exceeded since some of the indices to be filled never occur in randomIndexToInsertAt. The numbers in usedIndices are repeated.
Full code is atlink

It likely does not solve your problem, but why do you use recursion (which results in the Max call stack exceeded) instead of using a while loop in the generateRandomFruits with a maximum number of iterations?

@t.niese when I use a while loop, I get exceeded 10001 iterations - possible infinite loop

Regarding: I want to fill an array of size 12 with fruits such that every fruit in the new array has even number of occurrences. Is there a reason why you don't use an array of 6 and once it is filled double the number of each fruit?

when I use a while loop, I get exceeded 10001 iterations - possible infinite loop sure, that's why I said with a maximum number of iterations. It won't solve your problem, but recursion is most of the time bad.

@t.niese I never thought of that

The problem is that you have an infinite recursive "loop", as generateRandomFruits calls generateRandomFruits again and again and again.
Secondly you used a retry-system with recursion where you tell it to assign a fruit timesToRepeat times. But this ignores that you might already have successfully assigned one (or more) fruits. And so you end up in a situation where you overshoot the number of fruits to assign and will reach 12 earlier than expected.
Although you could fix all this, it is better is to avoid that you have to retry. Instead of randomly choosing a target index, just push the selections to the target array, and then shuffle it.
As you need to make sure to have an even number of selections of the selected fruits, you could select only 6 random fruits (each time from the whole list of fruits), and then add them to your result twice. This way you ensure that you have an even number of each selected fruit.
Finally shuffle the result array to have a random distribution. For this you can use one of the popular solutions from How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?.
In the below snippet I used a simplified fruits-array, as the object structure of the fruits is not relevant for this problem. So here they are just letters:


function shuffle(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[j], array[i]] = [array[i], array[j]]
    }
}

// Simplified fruits list (the structure of the elements is not relevant) 
const fruitsList = [
  "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
];

const randomOrderedFruits = [];
// Make 6 random selection and double each of them:
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const randomIndexOfFruit = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruitsList.length);
    const fruit = fruitsList[randomIndexOfFruit];
    randomOrderedFruits.push(fruit, fruit);
}
// ... and then shuffle:
shuffle(randomOrderedFruits);

console.log(randomOrderedFruits);




Might not be your core problem, but the following
const arrLength = Object.keys(randomOrderedFruits).length;

should be
const arrLength = randomOrderedFruits.length;

since it is an array, not a key/value object.

No, when an array is filled at random indices, the length property gives wrong value. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/31065075/5599387
